# What is the right way to deploy Node/Express/Mongo/React app with Docker?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, docker

I have built an app using Node/Express/Mongo on the backend and React/Redux on the frontend. Now I am trying to figure out how to properly deploy this app using Docker.

Can you give me some advice on how to do this correctly?

- Should I have 3 containers, one for node, one for mongo, and one for serving frontend files?
- What is the right way to serve React in production?

Are there some good examples/tutorials about doing this?

Comment: I think you are talking about [MERN](http://mern.io/), right?

Comment: For mern, I used 3 separate docker container, one for mongodb database, another for api and the last one for front-end

Comment: Wondering what is the current standard way of deploying a MERN App.